# Fast Voxel Traversal Algorithm with negative direction

Tags: xna, raytracing

I'm trying to implement fast voxel traversal algorithm and calculate T and M according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367071/how-do-i-initialize-the-t-variables-in-a-fast-voxel-traversal-algorithm-for-ray) (T is tDelta, M is tMax). All is good if the two components of the direction vector V are positive. But if at least one of them is negative, it's work wrong.

Green point is start, red is end. All seems correct.
[image: S.X > 0, S.Y > 0]

And now from bigger to less position.
[image: S.X < 0, S.Y < 0]

Traversal method:

```
private IEnumerable<Vector2> GetCrossedCells(Vector2 pPoint1, Vector2 pPoint2)
{
    Vector2 V = pPoint2 - pPoint1; // direction & distance vector
    if (V != Vector2.Zero)
    {
        Vector2 U = Vector2.Normalize(V); // direction unit vector
        Vector2 S = new Vector2(Math.Sign(U.X), Math.Sign(U.Y)); // sign vector
        Vector2 P = pPoint1; // position
        Vector2 G = new Vector2((int) Math.Floor(P.X / CELL_SIZE), (int) Math.Floor(P.Y / CELL_SIZE)); // grid coord
        Vector2 T = new Vector2(Math.Abs(CELL_SIZE / U.X), Math.Abs(CELL_SIZE / U.Y));
        Vector2 M = new Vector2(
            Single.IsInfinity(T.X) ? Single.PositiveInfinity : T.X * (1.0f - (P.X / CELL_SIZE) % 1),
            Single.IsInfinity(T.Y) ? Single.PositiveInfinity : T.Y * (1.0f - (P.Y / CELL_SIZE) % 1));

        Vector2 D = Vector2.Zero;
        bool isCanMoveByX = S.X != 0;
        bool isCanMoveByY = S.Y != 0;

        while (isCanMoveByX || isCanMoveByY)
        {
            yield return G;

            D = new Vector2(
                S.X > 0 ? (float) (Math.Floor(P.X / CELL_SIZE) + 1) * CELL_SIZE - P.X :
                S.X < 0 ? (float) (Math.Ceiling(P.X / CELL_SIZE) - 1) * CELL_SIZE - P.X :
                0,
                S.Y > 0 ? (float) (Math.Floor(P.Y / CELL_SIZE) + 1) * CELL_SIZE - P.Y :
                S.Y < 0 ? (float) (Math.Ceiling(P.Y / CELL_SIZE) - 1) * CELL_SIZE - P.Y :
                0);

            if (Math.Abs(V.X) <= Math.Abs(D.X))
            {
                D.X = V.X;
                isCanMoveByX = false;
            }

            if (Math.Abs(V.Y) <= Math.Abs(D.Y))
            {
                D.Y = V.Y;
                isCanMoveByY = false;
            }

            if (M.X <= M.Y)
            {
                M.X += T.X;
                G.X += S.X;
                if (isCanMoveByY)
                {
                    D.Y = U.Y / U.X * D.X; // U.X / U.Y = D.X / D.Y => U.X * D.Y = U.Y * D.X
                }
            }
            else
            {
                M.Y += T.Y;
                G.Y += S.Y;
                if (isCanMoveByX)
                {
                    D.X = U.X / U.Y * D.Y;
                }
            }

            V -= D;
            P += D;
        }
    }
}
```

In debug I can see that for example M.Y > M.X when should be the opposite if S.X < 0 or S.Y < 0.

Tell me please what my code work wrong for negative directions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**So, I solve it.**
I make code cleaner and problem is gone.

```
private IEnumerable<Vector2> GetCrossedCells(Vector2 pPoint1, Vector2 pPoint2)
{
    if (pPoint1 != pPoint2)
    {
        Vector2 V = (pPoint2 - pPoint1) / CELL_SIZE; // direction & distance vector
        Vector2 U = Vector2.Normalize(V); // direction unit vector
        Vector2 S = new Vector2(Math.Sign(U.X), Math.Sign(U.Y)); // sign vector
        Vector2 P = pPoint1 / CELL_SIZE; // position in grid coord system
        Vector2 G = new Vector2((int) Math.Floor(P.X), (int) Math.Floor(P.Y)); // grid coord
        Vector2 T = new Vector2(Math.Abs(CELL_SIZE / U.X), Math.Abs(CELL_SIZE / U.Y));
        Vector2 D = new Vector2(
            S.X > 0 ? 1 - P.X % 1 : S.X < 0 ? P.X % 1 : 0,
            S.Y > 0 ? 1 - P.Y % 1 : S.Y < 0 ? P.Y % 1 : 0);
        Vector2 M = new Vector2(
            Single.IsInfinity(T.X) || S.X == 0 ? Single.PositiveInfinity : T.X * D.X,
            Single.IsInfinity(T.Y) || S.Y == 0 ? Single.PositiveInfinity : T.Y * D.Y);

        bool isCanMoveByX = S.X != 0;
        bool isCanMoveByY = S.Y != 0;

        while (isCanMoveByX || isCanMoveByY)
        {
            yield return G;

            D = new Vector2(
                S.X > 0 ? (float) Math.Floor(P.X) + 1 - P.X :
                S.X < 0 ? (float) Math.Ceiling(P.X) - 1 - P.X :
                0,
                S.Y > 0 ? (float) Math.Floor(P.Y) + 1 - P.Y :
                S.Y < 0 ? (float) Math.Ceiling(P.Y) - 1 - P.Y :
                0);

            if (Math.Abs(V.X) <= Math.Abs(D.X))
            {
                D.X = V.X;
                isCanMoveByX = false;
            }

            if (Math.Abs(V.Y) <= Math.Abs(D.Y))
            {
                D.Y = V.Y;
                isCanMoveByY = false;
            }

            if (M.X <= M.Y)
            {
                M.X += T.X;
                G.X += S.X;
                if (isCanMoveByY)
                {
                    D.Y = U.Y / U.X * D.X; // U.X / U.Y = D.X / D.Y => U.X * D.Y = U.Y * D.X
                }
            }
            else
            {
                M.Y += T.Y;
                G.Y += S.Y;
                if (isCanMoveByX)
                {
                    D.X = U.X / U.Y * D.Y;
                }
            }

            V -= D;
            P += D;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

I'm began from removing redundant divisions on GRID_CELL and then notice mistake in M calculation.
There are using Frac() function in answer to the question, a link to which I provided. I'm calculate it like (1 - P % 1), but that is a case for S > 0, and there are should be (P % 1) if S < 0, and Inf for S = 0.

**Update 2**

Also there should be

```
Vector2 D = new Vector2(
    S.X > 0 ? (float) Math.Floor(P.X) + 1 - P.X :
    S.X < 0 ? (float) Math.Ceiling(P.X) - 1 - P.X :
    0,
    S.Y > 0 ? (float) Math.Floor(P.Y) + 1 - P.Y :
    S.Y < 0 ? (float) Math.Ceiling(P.Y) - 1 - P.Y :
    0);
```

Instead of

```
Vector2 D = new Vector2(
    S.X > 0 ? 1 - P.X % 1 : S.X < 0 ? P.X % 1 : 0,
    S.Y > 0 ? 1 - P.Y % 1 : S.Y < 0 ? P.Y % 1 : 0);
```

Because M will be infinity in case S < 0 and P haven't fractional part.

Comment: Many divisions by zero errors.

Comment: And also ray does not traverse correctly.

Comment: Code is sloppy, hard to see which are floats and which are integers.

Comment: Problematic code, mod or fmod ?

Comment: Vector2 D = new Vector2(
            S.X > 0 ? 1 - P.X % 1 : S.X < 0 ? P.X % 1 : 0,
            S.Y > 0 ? 1 - P.Y % 1 : S.Y < 0 ? P.Y % 1 : 0);